# How to customized Squid access log to show upload files just as its recording download files

Tags: squid, upload, logging

Just wondering , is there a way to check upload content or any data related to uploads using squid logs ? 
Any plugin or enhancement? any other viable option. grateful for any advice  . Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File uploads are just POST requests, and Squid logs the request methods used by default :

> The native format for Squid is: time elapsed remotehost code/status bytes method URL rfc931 peerstatus/peerhost type

So a command like `grep POST /var/log/squid/access.log` should give you all the POST requests, however that will also include a lot of requests that aren't file uploads, an example here :

```
1416604451.778    243 172.16.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 455 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/641455/editor-heartbeat/answer - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1416604497.047    245 172.16.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 327 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/641455/editor-heartbeat/answer - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1416604542.304    241 172.16.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 327 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/641455/editor-heartbeat/answer - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1416604587.562    241 172.16.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 327 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/641455/editor-heartbeat/answer - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1416604694.915    241 172.16.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 313 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
```

You could try filtering by request body size to get a better log, but without modification to Squid's source there is no way to log the request bodies, so you'll have a hard time getting the actual uploaded files.

Maybe look into [ICAP](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP) and create a program that responds to REQMOD and logs the request body before giving the request back to Squid ?