# Squid upload logs - how to view logs when user uploaded some data

Tags: squid

I am using squid proxy, but none of the existing solutions are not showing proper logs related to upload data, I need to view when user uploads any files into internet via squid, it should log, size, URL, file type if possible etc..

Need help, explored a lot, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Default squid's logformat directive does not contain the upload bytes counter, you would need to add it yourself. The value is %>st.

Reporting on traffic usage can be done using some third party log analysis tools that build reports over squid's access log, like SARG, lightsquid or others. Not sure if these have reporting on the uploads though - the [Web Safety](https://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_develop/traffic_monitoring/reports.html) will include upload reporting starting from version 7.5.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

I have tried keeping %>st - and I have uploaded 400mb file, from the logs I cannot see any number in bits/kilobits etc.. which says it is 500mb.

I have also tried with the other combinations mentioned in squid official - no luck http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/641455/how-to-customized-squid-access-log-to-show-upload-files-just-as-its-recording-do

Found this thread told to try with ICAP, but ICAP is HTTP protocol,  will it give HTTPS upload logs.